# Why does Apple payment sheet pop up twice?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-plugin

Ok, I have this issue 90% of times.

1. The user clicks the CTA button in the app
2. Apple payment button is shown
   [image]
3. The user subscribes
4. Then it seems everything has gone OK
   [image]
5. I get no error in the console, no report — nothing
6. then the Apple payment button pops up again
   [image]
7. If I don't put the password and if I don't subscribe the second time, the IAP will be unsuccessful.

I'm using this flutter plugin for IAP: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase. I also reported it there: https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_inapp_purchase/issues/318 but no one has picked it up.

I'm wondering whether it may be an iOS issue that many users are experiencing these days, besides the Flutter plugin?

maybe related: [What do I need to do once I request IAP (in-app purchase)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955611/what-do-i-need-to-do-once-i-request-iap-in-app-purchase/69956159#69956159)

Comment: I've seen the same issue on apps with native implementation. Didn't find a solution though... I've opened a ticket on https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ a few months ago but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a bug on Apple side that happens only during the testing with Sandbox testers: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/14088

Apparently, it's nothing to worry about since this issue should not persist when uploaded for production use.

Comment: I confirm this issue doesn't persist in production. The inconvenient thing is you'll have to recreate new test users every time.